# Monero fees are .0000456 after bulletproofs. Will it get smaller as more transactions go into a block?

Tags: transaction-fees, bulletproofs

Previously before bulletproofs. Fees were .002 on the low setting. Now they are .0000456 xmr. Will fees be even lower as more transactions go into a block? And if there are less transactions, fees would actually go up?